# Showing that $f : (0,2)\to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $f(x) := e^{2\pi i x}$ is not a covering map

Tags: general-topology

I am currently solving exercise 11.9 in the excellent book topological manifolds by John M. Lee.

> Let $f : (0,2)\to \mathbb{S}^1$ be defined by $f(x) := e^{2\pi i x}$.
>   Show that $f$ is not a covering map.

We do this by showing that $1 \in \mathbb{S}^1$ does not possess an evenly covered neighborhood. Assume that $U$ is an evenly covered neighborhood of $1$. Thus we find $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(1) \subseteq U$. The idea is now to calculate $f^{-1}(U)$. Obviously, we have $$f^{-1}(U) = (0,t) \cup (1 - t, 1 + t) \cup (2 - t,2)$$ for some appropriate choice of $t$. Now it is obvious, that for example $(0,t)$ is not homomorphically mapped onto $U$. I have some problem determining $t$. I mean, we have that $$|e^{2\pi i x} - 1| = 2 - 2\cos(2 \pi x) + \sin^2(2\pi x)$$ but this is a pain to solve. Hence my question:

- Is there another way of doing this?
- If no, how can I determine $f^{-1}(U)?$

Comment: If $f$ was a covering map, all fibres of $f$ would have to be homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out above by k.stm, observe that $\left\{ 1\right\} = f^{-1}(1)\not\cong f^{-1}(i) = \left\{ 1/2 , 3/2\right\} $ in which $\not\cong $ means that there is no bijection.

You can follow other ideas as well. For instance, if $g:(0,2)\to \mathbb{S} ^1 $  is a covering map, then it is a universal cover. In particular, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{S} ^1 $, $t\mapsto e ^{2\pi i t} $. Thereby the fibres of $g$ need to have infinite elements.
That is to say, every covering map $g:(0,2)\to \mathbb{S} ^1 $ needs to be such that $g^{-1}(x) $ has infinite elements (of course, for every $x\in \mathbb{S} ^1$).